# probability of a randomly 3 pieces broken stick s.t sum of 2 piece have greater length than the other

Tags: probability

A stick is randomly broken into 3 pieces . Determine the probability that the sum of the lengths of any 2 pieces is greater than the length of the third piece.

Comment: As I understand the problem, the probability is 1, since you can choose the largest two pieces to begin with.

Comment: the question probably meant any random 2 pieces chosen

Comment: This is a well known problem...you can read about the usual formulation [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r) or for some variants  [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Probability/TriProbability.shtml#Explanation)

Answer (score 0):

Geometric solution (non-strict): let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be lengths of pieces. Then in space with $xyz$ axes you have a triangle ($x+y+z=L, x\ge 0, y\ge 0, z \ge 0$). Total area of triangle corresponds to probability 1. Subsets of fitting pieces also correspond to a triangle, with area $1/4$ of the original one.